# Is it possible to customize the export file in moodle

Tags: moodle

I am using moodle 3.2 version with boost theme. I have to customize the export items. Is it possible?

For example : I have to export only First name , Last name of user details. Is it possible?

Please suggest your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I got solution . If you want to customize the export fields means you have to change in . php file. for example : To customize user details you have to change in rootfolder/admin/user/user_bulk_download.php file field array.

Thanks